# function positive, if positive on axis

Tags: calculus, functions, multivariable-calculus

I'm stuck on this little problem, and I'd appreciate some help

shouldn't be too hard, but I can't really get my head around it:

> Let $f: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ be a $C^1$ function such that \begin{cases}
> \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x,t) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,t), & \forall \, (x,t) \in \mathbb R^2 \\
> f(x,0) > 0, & \forall \, (x,0) \in \mathbb R^2
> \end{cases}
>
> Show that $f(x,t) >0$, $\forall \, (x,t) \in \mathbb R^2$.

By continuity I can show that there exists a region around the $x$-axis where this is true.
I'm not sure though how to extend this idea!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This answer might be overkill.** Feel free to share an easier solution, I am eager to see one.

The assumption on the partial derivatives implies the existence of $g\colon\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that for all $(x,t)\in\mathbb{R}^2$:
$$f(x,t)=g(x+t).$$
The second assumption implies that $g$ is non-negative, whence the result.

---

Let us establish the result I used implicitely:

> **Proposition.** Let $f\colon\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function. Assume that all the partial derivatives of $f$ are equal, then there exists $g\colon\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that for all $(x_1,\ldots,x_m)\in U$, one has:
>   $$f(x_1,\ldots,x_m)=g(x_1+\cdots+x_m).$$

**Proof.** Let us prove that $f$ is constant on all the hyperplane of equations $x_1+\cdots+x_m=k$, where $k\in\mathbb{R}$. Doing so, we will have that:
$$f(x_1,\ldots,x_m)=f(x_1+\cdots+x_m,0,\ldots,0).$$
Therefore, $g(t)=f(t,0,\cdots,0)$ suits the requirement and the result follows.

Let $\mathbf{x}:=(x_1,\ldots,x_m)$ and $\mathbf{y}:=(y_1,\cdots,y_m)$ such that:
$$x_1+\cdots+x_m=y_1+\cdots+y_m.$$
Let define $x\colon [0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$ by:
$$x(t)=(1-t)\mathbf{x}+t\mathbf{y}.$$
Also, let $F:=f\circ x\colon [0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, then $F$ is differentiable on $[0,1]$ and using chain rule, one has:
$$\dot{F}(t)=\sum_{k=1}^m(y_k-x_k)\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_k}(x(t))=\left(\sum_{k=1}^my_k-\sum_{k=1}^mx_k\right)\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}(x(t))=0.$$
Hence, $f(\mathbf{x})=F(0)=F(1)=f(\mathbf{y})$. $\Box$.

Comment: $f(x,t)= e^x + e^t$ satisfies first assumption. How it can be rewritten as $f(x,t)= g(x+t)$

Comment: @nonlinearthought It does not satisfy the equation, does $e^x=e^t$ for all $(x,t)$?

Comment: you are right,  I misread

Answer (score 2):

One of my students (I'm a TA) had the solution in like one minute after I posed the problem. It's the same idea as posted by C. Falcon above, just with a different path, more 'natural' to the problem.

the problem reduces to showing that $f(x_1,\cdots,x_n) = f(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i,0,\cdots,0)$

let $\gamma : [0,1] \to \mathbb R^n$ the path connecting $\mathbf x$ and $\mathbf y$ where

$$ \gamma (0) = \mathbf x = \begin{pmatrix} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, 
\qquad \gamma(1) = \mathbf y = \begin{pmatrix}  x_1 \\ x_2 \\ \vdots \\ x_n \end{pmatrix}, \\
\qquad \gamma(s) = \begin{pmatrix}  \sum_{i=1}^n x_i - s \, \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} x_i \\ s \, x_2 \\ \vdots \\ s \, x_n \end{pmatrix}, 
\qquad \dot \gamma = \begin{pmatrix} - \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} x_i \\ x_2 \\ \vdots \\ x_n \end{pmatrix}$$

then $$f(\gamma(0))- f(\gamma(1)) = \int_0^1 \nabla f \cdot \dot \gamma \, dt = 0 $$

since $\nabla f \propto (1,1,\cdots,1)^T$ and $\dot \gamma \perp (1,1,\cdots,1)^T$

Answer (score 0):

Alternative proof of [@C.Falcon 's Proposition](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2302040/386889): let
$$G:=f\circ h,\text{ where }h(y_1,\ldots,y_n)=\left(y_1,\ldots,y_{n-1},y_n-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}y_i\right).$$
Then, $\partial_1h(y_1,\ldots,y_n)=\left(1,0,\ldots,0,-1\right)$ hence
by the chain rule, $\partial_1G=(\partial_1f-\partial_nf)\circ h=0.$ Similarly,$$\partial_1G=\dots=\partial_{n-1}G=0,$$ i.e.
$$G(y_1,\ldots,y_n):=G(0,\ldots,0,y_n),$$
i.e.
$$f(x_1,\ldots,x_n):=f\left(0,\ldots,0,\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\right).$$