# Help needed for a question where the partial derivatives are the same

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Consider the following question

> Let $f: U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be a map on an open subset
> $U\subset \mathbb{R}^m$. Explain what it means for $f$ to be
> differentiable on $U$. If $g: V\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ is a
> differentiable map on an open subset $V\subset \mathbb{R}^p$ with
> $g(V)\subset U$, state and prove the Chain Rule for the derivative of
> the composite $f\circ g$. Suppose now $F:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow
> > \mathbb{R}$ is a differentiable function for which the partial
> derivatives $D_1F(x)=D_2F(x)=\cdots=D_nF(x)$ for all
> $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$. By considering the function
> $G:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $$
>  G(y_1,\ldots,y_n)=F\left(y_1,\ldots,y_{n-1},y_n-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}y_i\right),
> $$ or otherwise, show that there exists a differentiable function
> $h:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with
> $F(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=h(x_1+\cdots+x_n)$ at all points of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I am struggling to do the last part. Surely it something obvious but I can't see it. I thought that our function should be something that sends $R^n$ to $y_n - \frac{1}{n } \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}y_i$ but that clearly doesn't work as our input should be $R$. I tried to calculate the derivatives of $G$ explicitly, given the conditions for the partial derivatives of $F$, however, it gets very ugly.

**Question:**Could anybody point me in the right direction for the last part?

Comment: The hint is weird. I think there should be no $\frac1n$ in the definition of $G.$ Where does this exercise come from?

Comment: Hi, thank you for the suggestion. I saw your answer there. Is there any way to quickly calculate the partial derivatives or one has to get the Jacobian and everything to get to the result?

Comment: Simply chain rule, as written in ["my answer there"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2301992/function-positive-if-positive-on-axis/4674870#4674870). I just edited it to add some detail.

Comment: Thanks! That made it clearer.